# Browser push notifications with error "AbortError: Registration failed - push service not available"

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-analytics, notifications, web-push

I created a system to use browser push notifications with Firefox and Chrome to interact with site visitors more.

I'm looking at my Google Analytics events on why subscriptions are failing and the largest reason is that "push service not available".

I've looked all over trying to find a reason what this means and why this is so and I can't find anything on it.

This is the error straight from GA:

```
AbortError: Registration failed - push service not available
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like an error related to the browser push service (e.g. FCM for Chrome, Mozilla autopush for Firefox, etc.). Consider that in order to subscribe to push notifications, the browser needs to connect to its push service and get a new endpoint.

I don't think it's an error related to your website.

Comment: Thank you for you comment @collimarco . I know it's not a problem with the site because I am still getting subscribers, but as of Chrome 59 I started getting a ton of failures due to this error. Firefox doesn't seem to have this issue. I've looked at the release statements on Chrome 59 and I don't see changes to their push API. I'll have to dig around some more.

Comment: If I remember correctly I used to find that error with Opera. Then after the upgrade of Opera to the new version it disappeared. I think that Opera was using a legacy API to communicate with its push service (FCM) and thus it could not successfully register new endpoints.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Although I have my system setup so if anyone is on an old version of Chrome or Opera they can successfully sign up with FCM. But I am getting this mainly on Chrome 59, which should use the GCM method.